# Automatically updating created_by in the model

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I wanted to have a created_by field for my model, say Product, that is automatically updated and I am using FOSUserBundle and Doctrine2. What is the recommended way of inputting the User id into Product?

Can I do it in the Product model? I am not sure how to do so and any help would be wonderful. Thanks!

I want to do something like this in the model, but I don't know how to get the user id.

```
   /**
     * Set updatedBy
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * @param integer $updatedBy
     */
    public function setUpdatedBy($updatedBy=null)
    {
        if (is_null($updatedBy)) {
            $updatedBy = $user->id;
        }
        $this->updatedBy = $updatedBy;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To relate the user to the product you want to associate the two entities: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * You may need to use the full namespace above instead of just User if the
 * User entity is not in the same bundle e.g FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User
 * the example is just a guess of the top of my head for the fos namespace though
 */
protected $user;
```

and for the automatic update field you may be after lifecyclecallbacks:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setCreatedValue()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

### EDIT

This discussion talks about getting the container in the entity in which case you could then get the security.context and find the user id from that if you mean to associate the current user to the product they edited:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/symfony2/6scSB0Kgds0

```
//once you have the container you can get the session
$user= $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$updated_at = $user->getId();
```

Maybe that is what you are after, not sure it is a good idea to have the container in the entity though, could you not just set the user on the product in the update action in your product controller:

```
public function updateAction(){
   //....
   $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
   $product->setUser($user)
}
```

Comment: I would like to know how to get the user id from functions such as setCreatedBy(). Can I do it through the model?

Comment: I guess you could `return $this->getUser()->getId()` inside the function.  Could you give and example of use in your question and how you want it to work?

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer. I want to get the logged in user's id from the model. Is that possible?

Comment: I can't get $this->container in the Entity. I already extend ContainerAware in my Product entity. Am I to add something in services.yml? Any advice on that?

Comment: You need to also use an event subscriber https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/symfony2/WWIc8N7KZrg  this s a little beyond me though.  Subscribers are explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: Thanks Luke. I still can't solve the issue, still, an upvote for you. Thanks for the effort. I am not able to resolve this in time and will not be using Symfony2 due to time constraints.